# Recording a role given in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
##defines get_repeat role and reads the json and whatever
def get_repeatrole(client, message):
    with open('repeatrole.json', 'r') as c:
        prefixes = json.load(c)
    return roles[str(message.guild.id)]

##repeat - trying to custom role per server##
###REPEAT ROLE CHANGE###
@client.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['crr', 'repeatchange', 'changerr'])
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def changerepeatrole(ctx, role):
    with open('repeatrole.json', 'r') as c:
        roles = json.load(c)

    roles[str(ctx.guild.id)] = roled

    with open('repeatrole.json', 'w') as c:
        json.dump(roled, f, indent=4)

    ctx.send(f'{role} can now use the repeat command')
###REPEAT ROLE CHANGE###

###repeat command
@client.command()
@commands.has_role({get_repeatrole})
async def repeat(ctx, times: int, content='repeating...'):
    for i in range(times):
        await ctx.send(content)

@repeat.error
async def repeat_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, discord.ext.commands.errors.NotOwner):
        await ctx.send("You do not own this bot lol")
```

I can't seem to be able to record the role that is recorded. My aim was to figure out how to assign roles to specific commands via a command. I am not getting any error messages, but it's not working. Please help, thanks in advance :>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better save role ID in JSON

Below is the revised code:

```py
##defines get_repeat role and reads the json and whatever
def get_repeatrole(client, message):
    with open('repeatrole.json', 'r') as c:
        roles = json.load(c)
    return roles[str(message.guild.id)]

##repeat - trying to custom role per server##
###REPEAT ROLE CHANGE###
@client.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['crr', 'repeatchange', 'changerr'])
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def changerepeatrole(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    with open('repeatrole.json', 'r') as c:
        roles = json.load(c)

    roles[str(ctx.guild.id)] = role.id

    with open('repeatrole.json', 'w') as c:
        json.dump(roles, f, indent=4)

    await ctx.send(f'{role.mention} can now use the repeat command')
###REPEAT ROLE CHANGE###

###repeat command
@client.command()
async def repeat(ctx, times: int, content='repeating...'):
    if get_repeatrole(client, ctx) not in [i.id for i in ctx.author.roles]: return await ctx.send("You do not own this bot lol")
    for i in range(times):
        await ctx.send(content)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to save the id or role in the repeatrole.json file, and once again there doesn't appear to be any error message.
First I tried to change the f to a c in **json.dump(roles, f, indent=4)** but that didn't seem to work, then I tried changing **{role.mention}**  to **{discord.Role}** even though that probably doesn't work anyway, and it didn't...